# What's MySQL's SQL specific programming language name?

Tags: mysql, sql

You have T-SQL on SQL Server, PL/SQL on Oracle, what's the programming language on MySQL?

Comment: T-SQL and PL/SQL are the vendors' extensions to ANSI SQL, in a large part to support stored procedures. As far as I know MySQL never gave its procedural extension a trademarked name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you guys, you pointed me in the right direction, as MYSQL's page says:

"Our aim is to support the full ANSI/ISO SQL standard, but without making concessions to speed and quality of the code."

so it seems like the base language is SQL ANSI but they have some modifications as seen [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/extensions-to-ansi.html) ans [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/differences-from-ansi.html) (thanks to @Kugathasan Abimaran)

You can even run in [ANSI-only mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-mode.html).

However, no name is given to specific language. (thanks to @mmsmatt)

Answer (score 9):

[SQL/PSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM)

Comment: The proprietary additions to SQL/PSM used by MySQL are here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/extensions-to-ansi.html

Answer (score 2):

It uses [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) with a slight modification, you can refer it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/differences-from-ansi.html) [Official Documentation]